# Make dots work with function in jQuery Owl Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have some problems with the jQuery Owl Carousel.

I'm trying to get the dots to work with my function. I have tried to find the solution in other answers and tried different methods. Tried with trigger and also Slideby but can't solve it.

How can I make the dots work with my function?

Please help a student :)

```js
 $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
     loop:true,
     margin:10,
     dots: true,
     items: 3,
     slideBy: 3,
     nav:true,
     
     responsive:{
         0:{
             items:1
         },
         600:{
             items:1
         },
         1000:{
             items:1
         }
     }
 });
```

```css
.item {
  background: #04fbc7;
  height: 700px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 189px;
}

.owl-dots {
 text-align: center;
}


.owl-dot {
   cursor: pointer;
   height: 12px;
   width: 12px;
   margin: 0 2px;
   background-color: #ffffff;
   border-radius: 50%;
   display: inline-block;
   transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
   margin-top: 132px;
}

.active, .owl-dot:hover {
  background-color: #99f2df;
  
  
}
```

```html
function carousel_wiever () {
?>

<div class="wrapper owl-carousel owl-theme">
 
 <?php  
   $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'citat',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
   );
   query_posts( $args );
   // The Loop
   while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="item">
    <div class="custom_class">
     
     <div class="text1">
        <span class="quote"><?php meta('citatet'); ?></span>
       </div>
     <div class="text2">
        <span class="author"><?php meta('citerat_av'); ?></span>
       </div>
       </div> <!-- custom_class -->
       
       
       <div class="owl-dots">
        <div class="owl-dot active"><span></span></div>
        <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
        <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
      </div> 
     
       
       
       </div> <!-- item  -->   
         </div> <!-- wrapper -->
         
      
   <?php endwhile;
   // Reset Query
   wp_reset_query();   
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you have placed

```
<div class="owl-dots">
        <div class="owl-dot active"><span></span></div>
        <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
        <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
</div>
```

inside your `<div class="item">` and also inside your while loop and the closing wrapper div is also in your loop. So the dom structure will not output correct.

```
function carousel_wiever () {
?>

<div class="wrapper owl-carousel owl-theme">

<?php       
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'citat',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC'
        );
        query_posts( $args );
        // The Loop
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="item">
            <div class="custom_class">

                <div class="text1">
                            <span class="quote"><?php meta('citatet'); ?></span>
                        </div>
                <div class="text2">
                            <span class="author"><?php meta('citerat_av'); ?></span>
                        </div>
                </div> <!-- custom_class -->

            </div> <!-- item  -->     

        <?php endwhile;
        // Reset Query
        wp_reset_query();   
        ?>
        <div class="owl-dots">
            <div class="owl-dot active"><span></span></div>
            <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
            <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
        </div>  
</div> <!-- wrapper -->
<?php
}
?>
```

Secondly I would reconsider using query_posts, as it is very inefficiënt. Read more about that here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts

Comment: Ok now I understand. Thanks a lot! I will read more about the query_post.